# How to pass method in tabs (Ionic 2)

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework, methods, parameters

I try to pass a method with (click)="method()" but is not working in tabs ,
can anybody help me ?

**This is my tab.html :**

```html
<ion-tabs color="primary">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Carro" tabIcon="cart" tabBadge="2"  tabBadgeStyle="danger"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Perfil" tabIcon="md-person" (click)="method()"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call a method when tapping on a tab you can use the ionSelect on the tab element like this.

> Template

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="chat()" tabTitle="Show Modal"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

> Component

```
export class Tabs {
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  chat() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ChatPage);
    modal.present();
  }
}
```

You can check more on the [Ionic Api Page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/).

Comment: Thanks I'ts Working ;)